# Mutate a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to the dictionary concept and am stuck at a problem. I have compiled a dictionary for a bookstore, and within the dictionary the key is the author's last and first name, ie. 'Shakespeare,William'.

```
{'Dickens,Charles': [['Hard Times', '7', '27.00']],
 'Shakespeare,William': [['Rome And Juliet', '5', '5.99'],
                         ['Macbeth', '3', '7.99']]}
```

- Values are: book name, quantity on hand, and price. I want a function that can change the quantity of the book.
- The user will enter: the author's last name, then first, and then the name of the book, and then the new quantity they want.
- If the author does not exist it should say that there isn't an author by the name given, and same thing if the book doesn't exist.
- In a separate function, I need to add up the total quantity of this inventory. So as seen right now, it would be 5+3+7 = 15 books. I need a similar function for the price, but it should be essentially the same as that of the quantity I believe.

Thank you for your help.

I tried creating another dictionary with the books as the keys as follow:

```
def addBook(theInventory):
d = {}
first = input("Enter the first name: ")
last = input("Enter the last name: ")
first = first[0].upper() + first[1:].lower()
last = last[0].upper() + last[1:].lower()
name = last + "," + first
book = input("Enter the name of the book: ")
for name, books in sorted(theInventory.items()):
for title, qty, price in sorted(books):
        d[title] = []
        d[title].append(qty)
        d[title].append(price)

    d[book][0] = qty
```

I need to update theInventory with the new quantity, so theInventory would change in main(), but this isn't doing it. How can I make it so that d is referencing theInventory and changing the qty in there?

Comment: What have you tried/do you have a more specific question about where you're confused?

Comment: "The value is the book name, quantity on hand, and price" Actually the values are _lists_ of lists that contain name, quantity, and price triplets.

Comment: I can mutate the value of Macbeth by saying: theInventory['Shakespeare,William'][1][1] = "New number" but I want a more general statement where you can't just hard code it. I was mostly confused on how to take in the name of the book.

Comment: So you need to look up books by name, just like how you're looking up authors by name? Sounds like you should be using a dictionary for books just like you're using a dictionary for authors :)

Comment: I think it is not such a good idea to use the author as key: an author may have written more than only one book (especially if the author's name is Shakespeare )

Comment: It's a requirement for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came up with something like what you want. One problem I ran into was how you formatted your dictionary. In your original post, you had double lists for all dictionary values. I think it would be easier to format the dictionary like I did. One change I made to keep in mind is that in the changeQuantity() function, I switched the inventory number from a string to an int value. I'm not sure how you want to it be, but the format can easily be changed by making the newquant arg a string type. Hope this helped!

```
bookdict = {'Dickens,Charles': ['Hard Times', '7', '27.00'],
 'Shakespeare,William': [['Rome And Juliet', '5', '5.99'], ['Macbeth', '3', '7.99']]}

def changeQuantity(authorlast,authorfirst,bookname,newquant):
    bookfound = False
    author = str(authorlast)+','+str(authorfirst)
    if not author in bookdict:
        return "Author not in inventory"
    temp = bookdict.values()
    if type(bookdict[author][0]) == list:
        for entry in bookdict[author]:
            if entry[0] == bookname:
                entry[1] = newquant
                bookfound = True
    else:
        if bookdict[author][0] == bookname:
            bookdict[author][1] = newquant
            bookfound = True
    if bookfound == False:
        return "Book not in author inventory"
    return bookdict

def sumInventory():
    sum = 0
    for key in bookdict.keys():
        if type(bookdict[key][0]) == list:
            for entry in bookdict[key]:
                sum += int(entry[1])
        else:
            sum += int(bookdict[key][1])
    return sum


print changeQuantity("Dickens","Charles","Hard Times",2)
print changeQuantity("a","b","Hard Times",2)
print changeQuantity("Shakespeare", "William", "a", 7)
print sumInventory()
```

Output:

```
{'Shakespeare,William': [['Rome And Juliet', '5', '5.99'], ['Macbeth', '3', '7.99']], 'Dickens,Charles': ['Hard Times', 2, '27.00']}
Author not in inventory
Book not in author inventory
10
```

Comment: whoops, and you can totally delete line 9

Comment: I have to format the dictionary like I did for the requirement, as I'm creating it using a file.

Comment: Are you saying delete the temp. Also, can this be used for price?

Comment: yeah the temp can be deleted -- I didn't end up using it but forgot to take it out... Doesn't really matter if it's in there or not but it's just useless. As for the dictionary format -- the code should still work for the way you have it formatted currently... it's just a weird way to format it... Shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: And yes you can use the same logic for price. Instead of summing the 1st indice in the lists, you can sum the second.